# Creating a follow button? How to maximize efficiency?

Tags: python, sql, django, many-to-many, relational-database

I'm using django.  I want to create a follow button that once clicked will include the current user in the group of followers and then display the number of followers.  There is a unfollow button, too, which obviously does the opposite.

My question is how I could do this with the least number of queries possible and as efficient as possible.  I'm going to have a manytomany releationship between the user and the post(which is followed).  So I'm guessing once I click follow/unfollow button, there's going to be one query inserting a new object into the user, user_to_post, and post tables.  And retrieving the number of followers will take another query from the user_to_post table with count.  I'm not sure on this, but I'm assuming this approach would take a total of 4 queries(3 inserts/deletes, 1 select).

What is a better/more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO:

> And retrieving the number of followers will take another query from the user_to_post table with count.

1. You don't need to retrieve anything if you inserting something than you have it. Take this data and use them... Or even path them to your other function, like unnecessary variables or so...
   for e.g. you can have the number of user_to_post in your page. So it's present in your request. (if you rendering them) And you could path this variable through form and make var_count+1 or -1 depending on what you're increasing or decreasing
2. Why do you need to make 3 queries to post something? Show your (view or where you make query) code please... You can write it_to make a one query to write data to 3 Models... If you have fields that affect main model. For e.g. you have foreign key/many to many field with related model you can make 1 query and then access it's data through construction select_related(). See: [select related Django API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) and [Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model).

Fell free to aske more specific questions with your code...

Comment: 1. what if I display the number of total followers to anyone who sees the post?, then the variable would no longer only live on the page, therefore would require some kind of storage on the server.

Comment: 2. The query itself might be one in django code, but the code then executes multiple queries in sql.  for example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships would do joins for you, but doing a join is sometimes comparable to making two queries(depending on the situation) so I would like to limit the number of joins/queries I make

Comment: 1. You will 'POST' the data to your view right? Use jQuery or JavaScript simply, to change that number on page and your VIEW in django will change that code on the server side. So you will store data to your model but will not retrieve them from it again... Code will tell more :)

Comment: 2. About the query itself. It's not your concern in Django. Main point here is that if you making 1 query in django and have loses of productivity in SQL than it's not a suitable SQL server for your needs... Try to read about SQL servers speed comparisons or so. Maybe you expirencing some concrete problems with exact queryes? E.g. What if you're using MySQL right now and will switch to Postgre in future or even to GAE...